# Refresh partial page content in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

On dropdown's on-change I am calling my AngularJs Service that return data back in Json format. I can confirm that on-change event does call the service method and it does return data back however I am not been able to display the loaded date for some reasons. After some research my understanding is to use  $scope.$apply(); However It doesn't seems to be doing anything.

Given below is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="VacancyController">

    <p>Select a Vacancy:</p>
    <select ng-model="selectedVacancy" ng-options="x.name for x in vacancieslist" ng-change="getAllTeachers()"></select>
    <h1>Your selected Vacancy Title is : {{selectedVacancy.name}}</h1>
</div>

<div id="content" ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div ng-class="result">{{message}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
        <ul class="list-group tab-main" id="contact-list">


            <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="teacherModel in ListTeachers">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                    <img src="http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/men/49.jpg" alt="Scott Stevens" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
                </div>
                <a href="#" ng-click="openPanelRight(teacherModel)" title="Edit Record">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                        <span class="name">{{teacherModel.TeaFName}} {{teacherModel.TeaSName}}</span><br />
                        <span class="fa fa-comments text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{teacherModel.TeaEmail}}"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">{{teacherModel.TeaEmail}}</span><br /></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS Controller**

```
    app.controller('VacancyController', ['$scope', 'VacancyService' ,'$timeout', function ($scope, VacancyService, $timeout) {
    $scope.GetVacancies = function () {
        $scope.vacancieslist = [];

        var getData = VacancyService.Vacancies();
        getData.then(function (ord) {
            angular.forEach(ord.data, function (val) {
                if ($.trim(val).length > 0) {
                    var obj = new Object();
                    obj.name = val.VacTitle;
                    obj.id = val.VacNo;
                    if (val.VacNo > 0) {
                        $scope.vacancieslist.push(obj);
                    }
                }
            });
        }, function () {
            genericService.warningNotify("Error in getting List of Vacancies");
        });
    }

    $scope.getAllTeachers = function () {

        VacancyService.getAllData().then(function (response) {
            console.log('fired');
            $scope.ListTeachers = response.data;

            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.$apply();
            }, 0);

        });
    }

    $scope.GetVacancies();
}]);
```

**Service**

```
app.service("VacancyService", ['$http', '$location', function ($http, $location) {


    this.getAllData = function () {
        var response = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Home/GetAllData'
        });
        return response;
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution was to use parent -> child controller option and then use

```
$scope.$parent.function
```

to access the parent method and by doing so you don't even need to call .apply and it will bind the updated data for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div ng-controller="VacancyController">

        <p>Select a Vacancy:</p>
        <select ng-model="selectedVacancy" ng-options="x.name for x in vacancieslist" ng-change="getAllTeachers()"></select>
        <h1>Your selected Vacancy Title is : {{selectedVacancy.name}}</h1>


    <div id="content">
        <div ng-class="result">{{message}}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="list-group tab-main" id="contact-list">


                <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="teacherModel in ListTeachers">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                        <img src="http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/men/49.jpg" alt="Scott Stevens" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="openPanelRight(teacherModel)" title="Edit Record">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                            <span class="name">{{teacherModel.TeaFName}} {{teacherModel.TeaSName}}</span><br />
                            <span class="fa fa-comments text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{teacherModel.TeaEmail}}"></span>
                            <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">{{teacherModel.TeaEmail}}</span><br /></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try to add $scope.GetVacancies(); inside function getAllTeachers ();

Comment: It doesnt seems to be working, I understand You trying to pass the selected dropdown value which is find but the problem is it doesnot display the returned data back to the page.

Comment: Yes it does return data back to $scope.ListTeachers

Comment: I have replaced <li> with <table> but it makes no difference either.

Comment: <table>                                                                                                      <tr ng-repeat="teacherModel in ListTeachers">                                     <td>{{teacherModel.TeaFName}}</td>                                                  
 </tr>                                                                                                 
 </table>

Comment: <table></table> Yes that's what I did and it didn't work.

Comment: if the data does not display ,the data not return back definitely

Comment: But I checked in the console and It does return data back for sure.

Comment: Would setting $scope.ListTeachers with new data and calling  $scope.$apply();  not going to refresh the rendered data?

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh ng-controller="HomeController" not correct

Comment: the ng-controller="VacancyController" in div  is correct not dublicate the ng-controller

Comment: Sorry not clear what you trying to say here...My understanding is you can have multiple ng-Controller

Comment: You are placing a place to view the data in in different name controller you call the data form him

Comment: the controller ng-controller="HomeController" not found so return the data from server you must put the name controller you will added in the controller file

Comment: HomeController is one that display list of data when page load first time, then dropdown on-change load updated data and some how I need to display it to page, If you think I cannot have ng-Controller = HomeController that What should be the value in ng-controller when the page loads first time?

Comment: one ng-controller is enough to load all the data you needed but the controller will be the encapsulate all the html page and you can load data in different <div> Dependence on the method in controller file

Comment: after edit the code in html the data will be display definitely I hope I have helped you to solve the problem